# Does the inverse of a unimodular matrix with entries in $\{-1,0,1\}$ again have entries in $\{-1,0,1\}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, discrete-mathematics, linear-programming, integer-programming

A matrix $U \in \mathbb Z^{n \times n}$ with integer entries is called **unimodular** if its determinant is $+1$ or $-1$. The inverse of a unimodular matrix is again unimodular, since its entries as calculated by [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule#Finding_inverse_matrix) are integers divided by $+1$ or $-1$.

**Question:** If $U\in \mathbb Z^{n \times n}$ is a unimodular matrix that has only entries in $\{-1,0,1\}$, will its inverse $U^{-1}$ again have entries in $\{-1,0,1\}$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is "yes" if $U$ is nonsingular and *totally* unimodular, but in general, the answer is "no", as shown by the random counterexample below:
$$
\pmatrix{1&0&0\\ 1&1&0\\ -1&1&1}^{-1}=\pmatrix{1&0&0\\ -1&1&0\\ 2&-1&1}.
$$